# Dynamic import files with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lottie, bodymovin

I am creating an animations using Adobe After Effects and React Lottie and I have many json files generated by Bodymovin extension. I am importing files in that way:

```
import * as initial from './white_bird.json';
import * as hoverOn from './white_bird_hover_on.json';
import * as hoverOff from './white_bird_hover_off.json';
```

But, when I have e.g. 6 other components that look identically but differ from each other only with imported files. How can I write those lines upper in something like this:

```
const data = {
    initial: import * as initial(`./${some_param}.json`),
  };
```

**Note that I must import it like '* as' in another way this doesn't work**

Comment: Possibly import files with js and inject the contents to where you need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Dynamic import](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import#dynamic):

```
useEffect(() => {
  async loadData() {
    const data = await import(`./${some_param}.json`);
    setInitial(data);
  }

  loadData();
}, [])
```

and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if you have multiple requests:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async loadData() {
    const [initalData, hoverOnData, hoverOffData] = await Promise.all([
      import(`./${bird}.json`),
      import(`./${bird}_hover_on.json`),
      import(`./${bird}_hover_off.json`)
    ]);

    setInitial(initalData);
    setHoverOn(hoverOnData);
    setHoverOff(hoverOffData);
  }

  loadData();
}, [])
```

Comment: It only works with import * as variable_name without * as is not working

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, import returns a Promise and later I can easily set my data from file to state and now it works perfect.

```
const [initial, setInitial] = useState(null);
const [hoverOn, setHoverOn] = useState(null);
const [hoverOff, setHoverOff] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    import(`./${bird}.json`).then(data => setInitial(data));
    import(`./${bird}_hover_on.json`).then(data => setHoverOn(data));
    import(`./${bird}_hover_off.json`).then(data => setHoverOff(data));
  }, []);
```